# Concurrency issue (Deadlock?)

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, synchronization

I have one server and multiple clients. The server uses the first function through it's main function, and the clients call the second function through a thread (one client uses one thread to read in an infinite loop).

This is for a school assignment, the final purpose is to pass on the gameData struct through shared memory, to recreate the Arkanoid Game

```
BOOL EmitBroadcast(JOGO * structure) {//called by the server
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutexServer, WAIT_ABANDONED);
    structure->numPlayersAtivosAux = structure->numPlayersAtivos;

    memcpy(pBufGameData, structure, sizeof(JOGO));

    ReleaseMutex(hMutexServer);
    SetEvent(hServerHasWritten);

    return TRUE;
}

JOGO ReceiveBroadcast(JOGO * structure) {//used by the client's thread in loop
    //R/W de Michel Raynal 
    WaitForSingleObject(hServerHasWritten, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutexCliente, INFINITE);//lock r

    structure= &(*pBufGameData);

    if (structure->numPlayersAtivosAux == structure->numPlayersAtivos) {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutexServer, INFINITE);//lock g
    }

    structure= pBufGameData;

    (structure->numPlayersAtivosAux)--;
    memcpy(pBufGameData, structure, sizeof(JOGO));

    if (structure->numPlayersAtivosAux == 0) {
        ReleaseMutex(hMutexServer);//unlock g
        ResetEvent(hServerHasWritten);
    }

    ReleaseMutex(hMutexCliente);//unlock r

    return * structure;
}

void receiveLoop(LPVOID lParam) {//client thread loop function
    JOGO * gameInfoIn = (JOGO *)lParam;

    do {
        *gameInfoIn = ReceiveBroadcast(gameInfoIn);
        _tprintf(TEXT("\n%d"), gameInfoIn->vidas);

        Sleep(300);//testing purposes
    } while (closeThreadReceiveLoop || gameInfoIn->vidas != 0);
}
```

When I open more than one client and the server, after 1 successful read of each client, the server sends correctly and one client locks in the WaitForSingleObject(hMutexServer, INFINITE); line. Expected result is multiple successful reads.

Comment: If you can produce the deadlock on will, you can use a debugger and see what's deadlocking...

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject(hMutexServer, WAIT_ABANDONED);` what's that?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis that is a fix to a previous deadlock, because the first client thread was locking the server mutex and the last client read thread did not have permission to unlock it. so my hotfix was to wait on the abandoned server mutex

Comment: WAIT_ABANDONED is a return value, not a parameter that should be passed to WaitForSingleObject(). Did you mean `if (WaitForSingleObject(hMutexServer,INFINITE) == WAIT_ABANDONED)` ?

Comment: a common rule with locks is that a lock locks one specific data, and nothing else, which means that locks should be easily associated to their protected data, and should be locked _only if_ accessing this data

Comment: thanks @MichaelChourdakis and OznOg, michael's tip helped me solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as pointed out by  Michael Chourdakis  in the comments, I had a wrongful parameter in the WaitForSingleObject function. I worked this around by adding an event to the first client that blocks the serverMutex.

That makes the first client thread wait for the remaining client threads to finish. The last client thread triggers the event and the first client is able to terminate and release the server mutex lock.

Thanks for the comments  Michael Chourdakis and OznOg.